# Redirect with parameters laravel 5.3 | InvalidArgumentException in Response.php line 462

Tags: php, redirect, routes, parameter-passing, laravel-5.3

Hi I'm new to laravel and got stuck. 
in my app there are three types of users. their login data is kept in a single table(users table generated with auth), with a char to define the user type. What I want to do is when they log in, redirect them to relevant page with their user_id (obtained from the users table) on the url.
bottomline is I want to get the url as

> localhost:8000/ESProfile/15

where value 15 is the user_id of the table.
What I've done so far is below.

**In AuthenticatesUsers.php (auto generated from artisan auth)**

```
    protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    $userId = $user->id;
    if($user->type === 's') {
        return redirect('ESProfile', $userId);
    }
    else if($user->type === 'p') {
        return redirect('/ePProfile');
    }
    else if($user->type === 'i') {
        return redirect('/ePDashboard');
    }
}
```

**In web.php**

```
Route::get('ESProfile/{id}', function($id){ return view('ESeeker.details')->with('$id'); });
```

when I try to login, it gives

`InvalidArgumentException in UrlGenerator.php line 314: Route [ESProfile] not defined.` error.

along with

> 

```
in UrlGenerator.php line 314
at UrlGenerator->route('ESProfile', array('15'), true) in helpers.php line 692
at route('ESProfile', array('15')) in AuthenticatesUsers.php line 123
at LoginController->authenticated(object(Request), object(User)) in AuthenticatesUsers.php line 107
at LoginController->sendLoginResponse(object(Request)) in AuthenticatesUsers.php line 46
at LoginController->login(object(Request))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(LoginController), 'login'), array(object(Request))) in Controller.php line 55
at Controller->callAction('login', array(object(Request))) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 44
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(LoginController), 'login') in Route.php line 190
at Route->runController() in Route.php line 144
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 642
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in RedirectIfAuthenticated.php line 24
at RedirectIfAuthenticated->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in SubstituteBindings.php line 41
at SubstituteBindings->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 65
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 64
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 104
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 644
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 618
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 596
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 267
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 104
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 149
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 116
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
at require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\public\index.php') in server.php line 21
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many trials found my answer.

In RegistersUsers.php (auto generated file from php artisan make:auth)

```
    public function register(Request $request){

    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

    event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

    $this->guard()->login($user);
    $user = $request -> user();
        if(($user->type) == 's'){
            return $this->registered($request, $user)?: redirect()-> intended('/addPreferences/ESId='.$user->id);
        }
        if(($user->type) == 'p'){
            return $this->registered($request, $user)?: redirect()-> intended('/ePProfile/epID='.$user->id);
        }
     }
```

appending desired path with intended method did the trick. Thanks.
(special thanks goes to iCode)

Answer (score 0):

In your view, you must be using following code

```
route('ESProfile', ['id' => $id])
```

which will obviously fail because you have not defined `ESProfile` anywhere.

Change your route to following to wrok:

```
Route::get('ESProfile/{id}', function($id) {
  return view('ESeeker.details')->with('$id');
})->name('ESProfile');
```

Check docs for [named routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#named-routes).

Comment: Hi iCode for replying. I haven't used anything like that in the view. in the view, when data gets posted, the controller checks auth and if that's accurate checks for the char value, and then returns the id of the relevant entry, and my code gives `The HTTP status code "15" is not valid.` where 15 is the id of the logged in user. All I want is that to get the url as 'localhost:8000/ESProfile/15'. I can't just get the hang of it.